# how to access nth level hierarchy of xml using only XSL

Tags: xslt

I have to extract some records from a dynamically generated xml document whose hierarchy will be of a pre-defined format but the depth of the hierarchy will not be known. I am working in a .net framework and i know that we can use .net methods from xsl and that we need to use a recursive function in this situation in conventional programming paradigm. but i dont know how to work round it using pure xsl, which is what i need to do in this particular case.

Comment: We are not clairvoyant... you need to show some example input and output XML, along with the XSL you've tried.  Please read the [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Use `//` before node names example:

```
<xsl:template match="//temp">
  <!--do whatever you want-->
</xsl:template>
```

This will apply to all the elements that are having name `temp` appearing in any hierarchy ..